# Why doesn't this loop work?

Tags: c++, if-statement, do-while

Why doesn't this loop work? It creates a segmentation fault when the answer is not a y or n, but I thought I handled the problem and it didn't work. How can I fix this so the segmentation fault stops? I'm confused why it won't work.

```
int main()
{
    string yes = "y";
    string uyes = "Y";
    string no = "n";
    string uno = "N";
    string answer = " ";    
    do
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Welcome to the Red Fern Shipping Company where we ship your packages your way!\n";
        cout << "Do you want to ship a parcel? Y or N?\n";
        cin >> answer;
        do
        {
            if (answer == no || answer == uno)
            {
                cout << "Thank you! Come again!\n";
                system("PAUSE");
                return 0;
            }
            else if (answer == yes || answer == uyes)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.sync();
                cout << "That answer is invalid and cannot work. Please enter a 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.\n";
            }
        } while (answer != yes && answer != uyes && answer != no && answer != uno);

    } while (answer == yes || answer == uyes);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "How can I fix this?" Use the debugger

Comment: @MichielUitHetBroek Brilliant! I can't believe I missed that...haha thanks!

Comment: @justyournormalguy13 really you should learn how to use the debugger. You would have found the bug in no time. It will save you lots and lots of hours of scratching your head and asking questions on SO that are downvoted and closed. **Learn to use the debugger**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of 'answer' will for ever be unequal to yes/no if it is once since 'cin >> answer' is not stated in the inner do-while.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the inner loop is infinite

```
        do
        {
            if (answer == no || answer == uno)
            {
                cout << "Thank you! Come again!\n";
                system("PAUSE");
                return 0;
            }
            else if (answer == yes || answer == uyes)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.sync();
                cout << "That answer is invalid and cannot work. Please enter a 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.\n";
            }
        } while (answer != yes && answer != uyes && answer != no && answer != uno);
```

Inside the loop variable answer does not get renewed. You should insert statement

```
std::cin >> answer;
```

inside this inner loop.

I would place all if statements except one outside the inner loop. For example

```
        bool valid_answer;
        do
        {
            cin >> answer;

            valid_answer = answer == yes || answer == uyes || 
                                   answer == no || answer == uno;
            if ( !valid_answer )
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.sync();
                cout << "That answer is invalid and cannot work. Please enter a 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.\n";
            }
        } while ( !valid_answer );


    if (answer == no || answer == uno)
    {
        cout << "Thank you! Come again!\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```